# how to use the TUMBLE(time_attr, interval) window function in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink

I want to use TUMBLE(time_attr, interval) window function in My Flink SQL, but I don't know how to set the 'time_atttr' based on my data.

below is one line of my kafka source, it's json format, the body field containes the user logs:

```
{
body: [
    "user1,url1,2018-10-23 00:00:00;user2,url2,2018-10-23 00:01:00;user3,url3,2018-10-23 00:02:00"
]}
```

I user LATERAL TABLE and a User-Defined TableFunction flatmap the source to a new table `log`, and I want to group by the time and username, here is my code:

```
public class BodySplitFun extends TableFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Long>> {
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        public void eval(Row bodyRow) {
            String body = bodyRow.getField(0).toString();
            String[] lines = body.split(";");
            for (String line : lines) {
                String user = line.split(",")[0];
                String url = line.split(",")[1];
                String sTime = line.split(",")[2];
                collect(new Tuple3<>(user, url, sdf.parse(sTime).getTime());
            }
        }
    }
}

tblEnv.registerFunction("bodySplit", new BodySplitFun());
tblEnv.sqlUpdate(
       "select  
           count(username)
        from
           (
              SELECT
                 username,
                 url,
                 sTime 
              FROM
                 mySource LEFT JOIN LATERAL TABLE(bodySplit(body)) as T(username, url, sTime) ON TRUE
           )
           log
        group by 
           TUMBLE(log.sTime, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE), log.username");
```

when I run my program, I got these error message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Cannot apply 'TUMBLE' to arguments of type 'TUMBLE(<BIGINT>, <INTERVAL DAY>)'. Supported form(s): 'TUMBLE(<DATETIME>, <DATETIME_INTERVAL>)'
'TUMBLE(<DATETIME>, <DATETIME_INTERVAL>, <TIME>)'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:463)
    at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInst.ex(Resources.java:572)
    ... 49 more
```

How can I use the sTime field of table `log` for group by operation?